# Flask-MySQLdb autocommit?

Tags: python, mysql, flask, autocommit

I've been searching and googling my question but couldn't find any answers.

Is there any way to set *AUTOCOMMIT = True* in Flask-MySQLdb?

And aside from my problem. What's the best way to use MySQL in Flask?

I like to keep my code as simple and short as possible, do I have to create a new cursor everytime I want to execute a query and then commit it?

Like:

```
cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
cur.execute('select x from y')
result = cur.fetchall()
cur.execute('insert into..')
mysql.connection.commit() # why do I have to do this :D
```

I like the PHP way very much:

```
sumthn = mysql_query('select foo from bar')
```

I know I can create a function that does that for me, but is there any better way?

*can I find a better docs for flask-mysqldb? is there something better than flask-mysqldb?*

Answer (score 0):

you can set isolation level to 0 or to ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT

```
conn.set_isolation_level(psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)
```

or refer to this website http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html

Comment: psycopg2 is a Postgres driver. It doesn't work with MySQL.

Comment: How do I create a conn object in flask-mysqldb?